# TYPO3 Error | Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::readLLfile()

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x

I have TYPO3 Version 8.7.32 installed. But when I want do add a new content element, this error appears. Btw I updated from version 7 to 8.7.32. Everything else works.

Comment: Please check third-party or custom extensions for calling that method. I'm pretty sure, it is not called by TYPO3 core itself.

Answer (score 0):

The method you're using is deprecated, you can migrate to a new one. Check out below:

```
/** @var $languageFactory \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Localization\LocalizationFactory */
$languageFactory = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Localization\LocalizationFactory::class);
$languageFactory->getParsedData($fileToParse, $language, $renderCharset, $errorMode);
```

Ref. here: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/7.4/Deprecation-68122-GeneralUtilityReadLLfile.html